# JMH benchmarking for Java code involving lot of Mysql querying

Tags: java, unit-testing, benchmarking, jmh

Can we use JMH to test the performance of Java code in a small ORM like java framework which involves lot of queries to Database? From what I have read about JMH so far, it seems like it is only suitable for benchmarking very small units of Java code and not suitable for code involving querying or making network calls.

If JMH is not the right choice, What other testing frameworks could be used for testing our framework's java API performance?

Comment: What are you testing exactly ?

Comment: @user7294900 mainly trying to test time taken for execution of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to benchmark the code execution, you should isolate the database processes or make sure that the database time is not interfering into your tests. Bellow are some ideas:

1. You could define interfaces to isolate the database processes and add implementations with fixed values to return;
2. You could use an embedded H2 database with your benchmarks;